# ngStyle unexpected behavior, not updating on property change

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-style

I'm a little confused why `ngStyle` is not working as expected. I'm following a tutorial by Brad Traversy on Udemy, and we're instructed to use `ngStyle` like so:

`<h3 [ngStyle]="currentStyles" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h3>`

Which would rely on the `currentStyles` property set on the component class, as follows:

`currentStyles = {'padding-top': this.showExtended ? '15px': '0'}`

the `showExtended` property is a boolean, which is toggled by a method:

```
toggleExtended() {
      this.showExtended = !this.showExtended;
}
```

Expected behavior: the `padding-top` on the h3 element should change from 0 to 15px when this.showExtended is toggled from `false` to `true`. This property is indeed changing, as other parts of this component are reliant on it, and functioning as expected. However, It appears that `ngStyle` is only evaluating on first render, and not updating when the property of the component changes.

The solution I found was to make a method that returned a function scoped variable:

```
getCurrentStyles() {
      let styles = {
          'padding-top': this.showExtended ? '0' : '40px'
      }
      return styles;
  }
```

and set the element to

`<h3 [ngStyle]="getCurrentStyles()">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h3>`

This, in fact works as expected. To summarize: the ternary in that currentStyles object only evaluates on component mount, and that value then does not update when the value changes.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Minor update to get what you want.

```
toggleExtended() {
      this.showExtended = !this.showExtended;
      this.currentStyles = { 'padding-top': this.showExtended ? '15px': '0' };
}
```

Angular evaluates change to `currentStyles` object to trigger the redraw.

Comment: Thanks! So a change to `this.showExtended` wouldn't trigger a redraw then?

Comment: this,showExtended is not watched by Angular, this.currentStyles is.